# Handlebars execute only else statement

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm making simple registration form, and trying to just put a message that everything has gone well.
When entering  page I create a variable success which is set to false by default.

```
 router.get('/register',function(req,res,next){
   res.render('register',{title: "Registration", success: false, errors: req.session.errors});
   req.session.errors = null;
   req.session.success = null;
 });
```

Later in post route, I check for errors, and depending on amount redirect back

```
if(errors)
{
   req.session.success = false;
   req.session.errors = errors;
   res.redirect('/register');
}
else
{
   req.session.success = true;
   res.redirect('/register');
}
});
```

Problem starts when I want to display a text depending on success value. Below, else statement indeed works when there are errors in form, but 'if' is never shown despite true value.

```
<p> Registration </p>
    {{#if success}}
          <div class="okbox"> Now you can go and log in!</div>
    {{else}}
         {{#each errors}}
            <div class="errorbox">{{this.msg}}</div>
         {{/each}}   
    {{/if}}
```